# Parsing string which contain a function to object

Tags: javascript

I would like to parse this string :

```
var str1 = `{
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('hello');
  },
  content: "I'm a content",
}`;
```

and transform it to :

```
var str2 = {
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('hello');
  },
  content: "I'm a content",
};
```

I already tested JSON.parse(str1), but it doesn't work, same thing with eval(str1) any idea ?

Comment: `JSON.parse(str1)` doesn't work because thats not json. `eval` _should_ work, but since thats in a different scope, you won't see the `str1` from the outside.

Comment: The best solution is almost certainly "Redesign the system so you aren't passing stringified functions around in the first place".

Comment: Quentin is right. If you have to pass a function as string via json, you're absolutely doing something you shouldn't.

Comment: Eval should be avoided. It makes it hard for debugging, makes your code more vulnerable to attacks and theoretically is slower as the eval code does no get cached.

Comment: the idea was about to replace a js object from an string getting from the database, that's why i have no choice

Comment: @zeomega — You do have a choice. Put the *data* needed to initialise the object in the database, put the object constructor (with the methods) in the JavaScript, then combine the two when you pull the data out of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not valid javascript, otherwise it would work with eval. The problem is the first `{` is interpreted as a code block and not as the start of an object.

That one can be interpreted with eval:

```
`({
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('hello');
  },
  content: "I'm a content",
})`;
```

Or you could directly try and parse the whole string, including the declaration. It won't work in strict mode, though.

```
`var str1 = {
  sayHello: function() {
    console.log('hello');
  },
  content: "I'm a content",
}`
```

As the comments have suggested, I'm pretty sure there's a better way of doing what you're trying to do, you should not have to eval random js code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `eval`

```js
var str1 = `var obj = {
  sayHello: function () {
    console.log('hello');
  },
  content: "I'm a content",
}`;

eval(str1);

obj.sayHello();
```